# SQL Query - How to get smallest charge amount by sum number

Tags: sql-server, sum

I have problem with SQL Server Query, which got me stuck for 2 days. So, I have to calculate smallest charge amount which match this condition :

There is size allowance of 1.8, and if more than 1.8 then they will charge additional amount :

```
Size| Additional Charge Amount
------------------------------
0.3 | $1000
0.6 | $2000
0.9 | $3000
1.2 | $3000
```

For Example :

Example 1 :

```
Size| Additional Charge Amount
------------------------------
0.3 | $1000
0.6 | $0
1.2 | $0
```

This case have 2 options :

1. 0.3 and 0.6 in allowance of 1.8, so 1.2 will be charged $3000
2. 0.6 and 1.2 in allowance of 1.8, so 0.3 will be charged $1000

In this case, the smallest charge amount is $1000, so the additional charge amount will be in size 0.3 for $1000

Example 2 :

```
Size| Additional Charge Amount
------------------------------
0.6 | $0
0.6 | $0
0.6 | $0
1.2 | $3000
```

This case we have 2 options :

1. Allowance : the third 0.6 and the last 1.2, so size 0.6 on the first and second data will be charged additional amount, which result $2000 + $2000 = $4000 or
2. Allowance : the first, second, and third 0.6, so size 1.2 will be charged additional amount which result $3000.

Because we have to charge the smallest amount, so the additional charge amount will be in size 1.2 for $3000.

Example 3 :

```
Size| Additional Charge Amount
------------------------------
0.6 | $2000
0.6 | $0
1.2 | $0
```

This case will charge $2000, because 0.6 and 1.2 in allowance, so the first 0.6 will be charged additional amount.

Example 4 :

```
Size| Additional Charge Amount
------------------------------
0.3 | $0
0.3 | $0
0.6 | $0
0.6 | $0
```

There will be no additional charge for this case.

So, my thinking is, I have to know which bigger number sum up to 1.8, so I know the small size. Because, the bigger the size, more expensive the additional charge amount. But, if I have this logic, example 2 will be return wrong result ($4000).

Do you guys have any idea about how to do this case ? I tried many ways and searching for similar case, but I got nothing. Anyone can help ?

Comment: Can you labeled your example clearly `Example 1`, `Example 2`, `etc`. I am a bit confused with which description is referring to which example.

Comment: `This case we have 2 options : charge 0.6 and 0.6 which result $4000` this statement is referring to which sample data ? The one with 3 rows of `0.6` ? Then why only 2 rows of 0.6 is with additional charges ?

Comment: I already edit the question.. can you understand what I mean now ?

Comment: first of all, how do you determine for any scenario, which size is chargeable ? Like in `Example 2 Option 1`  why only 2 rows and not 3 of 0.6 is chargeable ? or in `Example 4` why none of the rows are chargeable ?

Comment: As I said, there are only 4 kind of size, 0.3; 0.6; 0.9; 1.2, every size have different charged amount. If the sum of the size more than 1.8, so additional amount will be charged. The data can have many rows, I have to figure out the smallest possible charged amount

Comment: Why none of the rows in `Example 4` is with additional charge ? How do you determine that  ?

Comment: maybe you can explain further on what do you mean by `There is size allowance of 1.8`

Comment: example 4 there will be no additional charge because the sum of the size is 1.8. If more than 1.8, additional amount will be charged

Comment: Keep in mind there is no concept of 'first' or 'last' record unless you have a column that tells you so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It determine which size is chargeable and which is not based on ascending or descending order of the size and then compare the total chargeable amount to determine what are the charges.

Note : a `ID` is introduced to calculate the cumulative sum of the `size` in the required manner.

```
--  create sample table & data
declare @charge table
(
    size    decimal(4,1),
    charge  int
)

insert into @charge (size, charge)
values (0.3, 1000), (0.6, 2000), (0.9, 3000), (1.2, 3000)

declare @sample1 table
(   
    id  int identity,
    size    decimal(4,1)
)
insert into @sample1 (size)
values (0.3), (0.6), (1.2)

declare @sample2 table
(
    id  int identity,
    size    decimal(4,1)
)
insert into @sample2 (size)
values (0.6), (0.6), (0.6), (1.2)

declare @sample3 table
(
    id  int identity,
    size    decimal(4,1)
)
insert into @sample3 (size)
values (0.6), (0.6), (1.2)

declare @sample4 table
(
    id  int identity,
    size    decimal(4,1)
)
insert into @sample4 (size)
values (0.3), (0.3), (0.6), (0.6)

-- the query
; with 
-- this cte gets the charge for each size. `cumm_size` is cummulative
-- running total for the size in ascending order (a) or descending order (d)
cte as
(
    select  s.size, c.charge,
            cumm_size_a = sum(s.size) over (order by s.size, id),
            cumm_size_d = sum(s.size) over (order by s.size desc, id)
    from    @sample1 s
            inner join @charge c    on  s.size  = c.size
),
-- this cte determine the charge by inspecting the value of `cumm_size`
-- less than 1.8, charge = 0
cte2 as
(
    select  *, 
            charge_a = case when cumm_size_a <= 1.8 then 0 else charge end,
            charge_d = case when cumm_size_d <= 1.8 then 0 else charge end
    from    cte
)
-- last part of the query
-- `sum(charge) over()` will gives you the total charge
-- comparing it between the ascending and descending method and return the lower of both
select  size, 
        charge = case   when    sum(charge_a) over() > sum(charge_d) over()
                        then    charge_d
                        else    charge_a
                        end
from    cte2 c
order by c.size
```

Comment: wow, you are so smart, i'm stuck on this for about 2 days++ and you just get it just in a few minutes.. can you help me to explain the query ?

Comment: updated the comments in between the query. You will understand better by looking at all the column in the last `select` statement.  just add `*` to the `select` statement to view all columns